# Decimal rate for GAE Task Queues possible?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I'm learning Google App Engine and experimenting with an application that does a lot of batch processing using Task Queues. It's just a test, so I don't want to enable billing yet. With a *bucket-size* of 1, a maximum *rate* of 1 and *max-concurrent-requests* of 1, goes over quota of *Datastore Write Operations* in about a hour.

Slowing down 50 times, should not go over quota, so I tried to set the rate to 0.02, it shows up correctly in the admin, but on my dev server tasks are not executed, they can be executed only manually.

Is this a known limitation? Is the minimum speed 1 per second?

**UPDATE**: I created a new application (since the other one is over quota for today), and the decimal rate works on GAE, so it seems a bug (or a feature?) of the dev server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in the dev_appserver. Can you please file a bug report against it?

Comment: Ok, [Issue 6480](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6480&thanks=6480&ts=1323141876)

Comment: Thank you for raising the bug. We have fixed this in 1.7.0.